# Defining Relativity of Simultaneity in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity

People often state that I can't define relativity of simultaneity in General Relativity.

However, can't I define it as the following:
Taking into account the light travel time (the time an observer "saw" an event minus the time for light to travel to the observer), will two events be simultaneous?

Comment: You seem to be confusing relativity of simultaneity with the clock synchronization procedure.

Comment: Relativity of simultaneity means the *inability* to do something (define simultaneity in a universal way), not the *ability* to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The relativity of simultaneity is a feature of special relativity (SR), where you can define globally inertial reference frames in uniform relative motion.

In general relativity (GR), due to inhomogeneities in the gravitational field, this is no longer possible. In GR you can define only locally inertial frames, i.e. frames which follow the motion of individual freely falling particles in small enough regions of spacetime.

If you measure the time two separated events occur in a locally inertial frame, how to relate them in another locally inertial frame which is far away?

Comment: But I can also do the measurement of "Taking into account the light travel time (the time an observer "saw" an event minus the time for light to travel to the observer), will two events be simultaneous?" in two different locally inertial frame, then ask the question "are they simultaneous in both frames?".

Comment: @TheFirstStyleBender That gets tricky in GR, due to the [Shapiro time delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_time_delay). In perfectly flat spacetime, light always has a speed of *c*, but in curved spacetime that's only true for local measurements, if you attempt to measure the speed of light over large distances with intervening gravity sources then you may get a different speed.